# Тире в предложении с вопросительной интонацией

Tags: тире

Оправдано ли тире в такой конструкции (помечено вопросам)?

– Ну ты даёшь! – хмыкнул Николя. – Ты хотя бы прогулялся со мной по парку что ли или спросил, как у меня дела… Жюль! Ты представляешь(?) – он не спросил.

Comment: Иллюзия вопросительной интонации.

Comment: ты представляешь - это вроде обращения. Представляешь, он не спросил. Но можно и тире поставить. Ваня - (а ведь/но) он не спросил. А можно и не ставить: представь себе, он не спросил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реплика скорее эмоциональная, чем вопросительная. После призыва *представить* следует то, что должно удивить. И логично будет видеть *удивительный знак* в конце фразы, как это сделано у Нины Дашевской (***Представляешь, наш мальчик — в Брюсселе!***), хотя примеров иного оформления подобной конструкции достаточно много:

> Ты представляешь — какие перспективы там открываются? (Андрей Геласимов)
>
> Ты представляешь? На голубом глазу. (Андрей Волос)
>
> Представляешь, в вагоне только три купе, и в каждом отдельная ванна.
> (Виктор Пелевин)
>
> Представляешь, я на курорте. (Александр Мардань)